# Transform elements with some properties using group by attribute value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement to transform below XML

```
<XML>
   <Obj1 attr1="value1" attr2="value2" attr="10"/>
   <Test1 tatt1="tvalue1" tatt2="tvalue2" attr="10"/>
   <Obj1 attr1="value11" attr2="value21" attr="101"/>
   <Test1 tatt1="tvalue11" tatt2="tvalue21" attr="101"/>
   <Obj1 attr1="value12" attr2="value22" attr="102"/>
   <Test1 tatt1="tvalue12" tatt2="tvalue22" attr="102"/>
</XML>
```

I want transformed XML like

```
<XML>
   <Obj1 attr1="value1" attr2="value2" attr="10" tatt1="tvalue1"/>
   <Obj1 attr1="value11" attr2="value21" attr="101" tatt1="tvalue11"/>
   <Obj1 attr1="value12" attr2="value22" attr="102" tatt1="tvalue12"/>
</XML>
```

I have achieved it through normal pattern matching and finding the matching attribute value in all other elements. I doubt about the performance. So wanted to check if it can be done using group-by attribute name and combining attributes from all such elements into one.

I want to merge contents (all attributes of Obj1 and selected attributes from matching elements) of all matching elements having attr= into transformed XML.

Comment: Please explain in words the logic that needs to be applied here. If you have a working stylesheet, add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="tests" match="Test1" use="@attr" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> <!-- Identity template: copies all nodes to the output - unless a more specific template matches -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Obj1">      <!-- Modifies all 'Obj1'  elements -->
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*|key('tests',@attr)/@tatt1" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Test1" />   <!-- Removes all 'Test1' elements from the output -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output should be as desired. And the use of the `xsl:key` will improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks @zx485. Will the document be processed 3 times. First copy all elements, second modify element and third remove unnecessary. Will this be a performance hit?

Comment: No! Your interpretation of the stylesheet is procedural/fundamentally wrong. The templates are not processed in linear order (as you suggested), but in a pattern matching way: the template the matches the current state/condition will get executed. I suggest that you consult a tutorial about XSLT and/or functional programming versus imperative programming to get the difference.

Comment: zx485 Thanks. I think there is the difference between the understanding I need to correct.

One more thing - I am extending my requirement. It can have different elements like Test1, Test2 and ... and all have different set of attributes to copy to Obj1. How to resolve such case?

Comment: You can change the `<xsl:key name="tests" match="Test1" use="@attr" />` to `<xsl:key name="tests" match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'Test')]" use="@attr" />` to match different `Test*` elements. But copying a different attribute-set for each is beyond the scope of this question. I suggest that you accept this answer and think of a good [mcve] for a follow-up question including all of the requirements you desire.

Comment: @zx486 It worked and performed well as well with big XML file size. The only change I required was to modify

<xsl:template match="Obj1">

to

<xsl:template match="//Obj1">

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, you could so simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/XML">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Obj1">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::Test1[1]/@tatt1"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want do it by matching the value of the `attr` attribute instead of by position, then it would become:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="test" match="Test1" use="@attr"/>

<xsl:template match="/XML">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Obj1">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('test', @attr)/@tatt1"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: how can I extend it to have Test1, Test2 with diff set of attributes to copy from both these elements to Obj1

Comment: I don't know. Either edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: I have updated my question with descriptive requirement.

Comment: Your description is too vague. We need to see an actual example, with all possible element names and an exact list of which attributes you want to collect.